# Why "SADAIC" and not "SADAYC"?

Tags: abreviaturas, argentina

Lo siento, yo no hablo español.

The name of [this organisation](http://www.sadaic.org.ar) is *Sociedad Argentina de Autores y Compositores de Música*.

So why the acronym **SADAIC** and not **SADAYC**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Acronyms in Spanish should normally include just the primary words (excluding prepositions like *de* or *en*), for which we'd presume the acronym *SAACM*.  Not the most pronunciable thing, the two options would be either spelling out the letters as /esja:θe:me/ which might just be heard read back as *SACM*, or reading it out which is tough given the *-cm*.

So by adding the *-d-* and *-y-*, you get something a bit more pronounceable, except for the *-m*: SADAYCM: /sadaik/ + *m*.  Clearly they decided to just drop the M because it's a pain to say, so that gets them *SADAYC*.

A *y* is generally not allowed in the interior of a word unless between vowels (exceptions: soy/doy/voy with post-positioned object pronouns as in *voyme*), so they probably decided that *SADAIC* made more sense as its abbreviation.

**Update**: as angus points out, the *i* stays on its own syllable.  Looking around online, it's common for it to be written with only an initial cap, as *Sadaíc*.  Based on that, I'd say the use of the *i* is simply because up until the most recent orthography of the language, a *y* couldn't have an accent and obligatorily would form a diphthong with the preceding syllable.  Technically, under the new orthography, they could use *Sadaýc*, but since they're already using it with an *i*, they're unlikely to change now.

Comment: Just FYI, it's pronounced "sadaíc".

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Why do you write *Sadaíc* rather than *Sadaic* ?

Comment: Thank you for this good answer. [But in Colombia there is the *SAYCO* : *Sociedad de Autores y Compositores de Colombia*](http://www.sayco.org).

Comment: They probably pronounce it as /sajko/ with the *y* creating a diphthong thus matching the English word *psycho*.

Comment: As for Colombia, because *saco* is a word (with multiple very different meanings — I take out, sack, and right away), they just added in the *y* so it'd be unambiguous. It's not quite an exact science, unfortunately. Probably a better way to think about it is when you wonder why EKG isn't ECG like it should be in English. Unambiguity trumps technical correctness

Comment: Sorry for all the comments — they can't be edited so have to give a new one. Normally, *Sadaic* would be said into two syllables (in Englishish: sah-DYKE). The accent tells us to stress the *i* which also puts it in its own syllable, giving us sah-dah-EEK. You wouldn't use an accent in the capitals form because, in theory, it's just an acronym, but when spelled with just an initial cap, it now functions as any other word in Spanish and needs to follow Spanish rules of accenting.

Answer (score 1):

According to them: "SADAIC is an abbreviation of the Argentine Society of Authors and Composers, where for a specific typographic treatment "I" was changed to "Y", adapting the acronym that represents us and for which we are recognized worldwide. Cheers!"

Source:SADAIC @ Facebook